# About second order linear differencial equation with second term

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals

I'm reading a physic paper with some math in it. I'm struggling following the author's mathematical equalities about differential equation. I explain:

Let $p$ a solution of
$$
p''\left(x\right) - k^2 p\left(x\right) = -Q\left(x\right)
$$
where $k$ is a constant and $Q$ is a function which is not known here. Let $p$ be decomposed in
$$
p = p_h + p_s
$$
with $p_h$ being the homogeneous solution and $p_s$ a particular solution. As the author, I've found
$$
p_h = A e^{-kx} + Be^{kx}
$$

Then the author writes that he computed the Wronskian, which I've done, and it gives
$$W =2k$$. So far so good. Then he obtains, and I don't know how :

$$p_s = -\frac{e^{-kx}}{2k}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{kx}Q\left(s\right)\text{d}s+\frac{e^{kx}}{2k}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kx}Q\left(s\right)\text{d}s$$

which does not correspond to Wolfram's solution which still has $x$ instead of $\infty$ in the integrals upper bounds and where exponentials within the integrals depend on $s$ and not on $x$. Wolfram's solution:

$$p_s = -\frac{e^{-kx}}{2k}\int_{0}^{x}e^{ks}Q\left(s\right)\text{d}s+e^{kx}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^{-ks}Q\left(s\right)}{2k}\text{d}s$$

Even more intriguing, the authors finally reduce his expression to:
$$
p_s = \frac{1}{2k}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-k\left|x-s\right|}Q\left(s\right)\text{d}s
$$
where I see no clue about how this absolute value appears. What I've got is
$$p_s = \frac{1}{2k}\int_{0}^{x}\left[e^{k\left(x-s\right)}-e^{k\left(s-x\right)}\right]Q\left(s\right)\text{d}s$$
and I don't see what's the trick here.

Can someone give me a bit more detail to understand how this is written.

[image]

Comment: What you write is correct and what you cite is strange. Here it would be illustrating to have an image of the cited formula or section, or a link to a public version of the paper.

Comment: Okay thank you, i'll provide that. Not sure i'm allowed to give a link to it but i'll provide just an image

Comment: The original is indeed sloppy. What is $\hat Q$, is it modified from some $Q$? Why the insistence on the index in $x_2,X_2$? The decision of when and when not to write the proper arguments of a function. // The last formula, to the contrary, is not that strange, that is the solution formula with Green kernel. It almost seems as if the intend was to provide a short and quick derivation of this formula, and that this became too quick.

Comment: It's a Fourier transform of some $Q$. In tems of index, I have no idea. This is a physic paper, and I think rigor is not their priority. At least as I see it. The problem is I don't understand how they obtain the solution. Yes we can obtain the same with Green kernel (I'm not really familiar with Green function, I just know the basics). But I still dont see how the final answer pops out. Where does that $\infty$ comes from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended calculation seems to be a transition from the variation-of-constants formula to the Green-kernel formula.

To get from your formula to the Green-kernel formula, consider that
$$
e^{kx}\int_0^xe^{-ks}Q(s)\,ds=-e^{kx}\int_x^{\infty}e^{-ks}Q(s)\,ds+e^{kx}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ks}Q(s)\,ds
$$
Now the integral factor in the last term is a constant, so that the last term can be shifted into the homogeneous/complementary solution. What then remains of the particular solution is
$$
y_p(x)=-\int_0^x\frac{e^{-k(x-s)}}{2k}Q(s)\,ds-\int_x^{\infty}\frac{e^{-k(s-x)}}{2k}Q(s)\,ds
=-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-k|x-s|}}{2k}Q(s)\,ds
$$
The negative sign here is correct, it is missing in the original. The Green kernel function needs to have a $V$ or $r$ shape, thus is negative due to the zero boundary conditions.